# How to return index of an element with probability of the element's value divided by sum of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, probability, binary-search

Given an array and a value k, write a function to return index of element that equals to k with the probability of k/sum(input array). Assume there is no duplicate number in input array.

For example, if the input array is 1,4,2,3. The function should have the following behavior:

return 0 with probability 1/10;

return 1 with probability 4/10;

return 2 with probability 2/10;

return 3 with probability 3/10;

Question 2: How to deal with it if there are duplicates in the array?

I was thinking binary search is good to find an element in array, however I haven't figured out how to connect it with the probability.

**Edited**:
As suggested, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/how-to-pick-an-item-by-its-probability) is similar to my question. However, its solution was not what I expected. I was looking for a solution that is embedded with **binary search**, which potentially decreases time complexity.

A [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553970/find-the-first-element-in-an-array-that-is-greater-than-the-target) about given a key, how to use binary search to find the first element bigger than key in sorted array.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the size of the array and the size of numbers stored as its elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select element from array with probability proportional to its value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489449/select-element-from-array-with-probability-proportional-to-its-value)

Comment: Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/

Comment: There is no restrictions. The size can be huge and the number can be large. Thank you for the links. I didn't found them while I was searching. However, after I read them, their solutions were not what I expect. Sorting an array is O(nlogn), I do like Juan Lopes solution, which is O(n) and has less constant c for O(cn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an accumulated array from the input, where `B[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[i]`. Generate a random int `x` between `1` and `sum(A)`, then binary search B for the first element not lesser than `x`.

Here's an example in Python (using Python's `bisect` module, that's essentialy a binary search).

```py
import random, bisect, collections

def make_random(A):
    s = sum(A)
    B = list(A)
    for i in xrange(1, len(B)):
        B[i] += B[i-1]
    def fn():
        r = random.randint(1, s)
        return bisect.bisect_left(B, r)
    return fn

rnd = make_random([1,4,2,3])

c = collections.Counter()
for i in xrange(10000):
    c[rnd()]+=1

print c
```

The result will look like:

```
Counter({1: 3960, 3: 3036, 2: 1992, 0: 1012})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum all the elements(denote the sum S) and then generate a random number r from 1 to S. Then iterate over all numbers a<sub>i</sub>. If a<sub>i</sub> is not less than r, return a<sub>i</sub>. Otherwise subtract a<sub>i</sub> from r. Continue on until a value is returned. If you have a single query, you will not be able to improve over this solution.

EDIT(credit to JuanLopez):
However if you are about to answer multiple queries, you can use precomputation as in [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) and combine it with binary search to find the exact position k for which sum <sup>x</sup><sub>i=0</sub>a<sub>i</sub> will be less than k and x is maximum. Note that after you do prefix sum precomputation you can compute sum <sup>x</sup><sub>i=0</sub>a<sub>i</sub> in constant time.

Comment: Binary search will help here. Instead of iterating over all numbers in O(n), you can perform a binary search on the accumulated array in O(log n).

Comment: @JuanLopes good point. I have edited my answer to include the suggested improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, subtraction will continue forever in worst case. Prefix sum probably is better especially when the array is  large.

Answer (score 0):

> Given an array and a value k, write a function to return index of
>   element that equals to k with the probability of k/sum(input array)

You can reduce your problem to uniform sampling from `[1, sum]`. The idea is to use the cumulative list `cum_distr` of your initial list and uniformly sample a number `r` in `[1,sum]` and find the highest `i` such `r<=cum_distr[i]`

```
import random


def get_cum_distr(distr):
    cum_distr = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(distr)):
        sum += distr[i]
        cum_distr.append(sum)
    return cum_distr


def sampler(cum_distr):
    r = random.randint(1, cum_distr[-1])
    i = 0
    while r > cum_distr[i]:
        i += 1
    return i


distr = [1, 4, 2, 3]
cum_distr = get_cum_distr(distr)
#test sampler
sample_size = 100000
samples = []
count = dict()
for _ in range(sample_size):
    r = sampler(cum_distr)
    if r in count:
        count[r] += 1
    else:
        count[r] = 1
#{0: 9996, 1: 40115, 2: 19934, 3: 29955}
```

Note that if the searching for the index is expensive you can use binary search instead since `cum_distr` is non-descresing.

> How to deal with it if there are duplicates in the array?

It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the naive sampler (*and in fact it is*)
, but there is a subtility in the *order* in which the elements are examined.
By putting the largest weights in front, the loop will often complete in only a couple of iterations. So, if the distribution is very skew, this method could be faster *on average*.

[ I used this trick to sample from the stochastic vectors used in the Markov-nodes in Wakkerbot ]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct samp {
    int ret;
    unsigned weight;
    } array[4] = {{ 1,4}, { 3,3}, {2,2}, { 0,1} };

unsigned sumweight = 10;

     /* this is a *terrible* way to obtain a uniform random value */
#define urand(n) (random() % (n))

int sample(void)
{
unsigned idx, val;

val = urand(sumweight);

for( idx=0; idx < 4; idx++ ) {
    if (val < array[idx].weight) return array[idx].ret;
    val -= array[idx].weight;
    }
return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
int ret;
unsigned loop;

for (loop = 0; loop < 20; loop++) {
    ret = sample();
    printf("%u: %d\n" , loop, ret);
    }
return 0;
}
```